# pdfRender in android studio using API min 17

Tags: android, android-studio, pdfrenderer

i'm creating project using android studio, my project using pdfRender from android developer, but it just can using API 23. when i'm change using API 17, the libary is error. please give me solution.

Comment: error like this image :

Comment: like this image http://aanelzam.com/richi/aaa.png

Comment: yeah, the function is new to api level 21 and will not work in older android versions.

Comment: So,what can i do for older api.any solution?

Comment: Can you tell me what is library that usually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As may you notice this library was added in API 21, as it is described below: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html

For older API, please check one of the alternatives mentioned in this post:

> Google Code has some nice source code for reading pdf in android
>
> - [Android PDF Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)
> - [VuDroid](http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/)
> - [APDFViewer](http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/)
> - [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)
> - [android-pdf](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/)
>
> I hope there is something you can use
>
> From: [Pdf viewer api/library for android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728920/pdf-viewer-api-library-for-android-app)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try one of them

Comment: @AanElzam I you would find it useful, please mark it as an answer for any other guy looking for solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Ive found a more recent library that could help us to make pdf works since API 11.
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Hope this help other people looking for this.